# periodiccallback of asynchronous function

Tags: python, asynchronous, parallel-processing, tornado, periodicity

Does `PeriodicCallback` ensure no parallel executions? Is the callback triggered while a previous triggered one is still running or does it ensure that there is only one callback running at a time? As far as I can see the later one is true, but I want to be sure! I should control that time of asynchronous function is no longer than next `periodiccallback` scheduler.

For example:

If I have a `periodiccallback` every 5 seconds and my function time sometimes (because makes http request etc) is longer (for example 7 second), how can I jump the "10 second" and pass to 15? Only when it happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tornado docs says

> If the callback runs for longer than callback_time milliseconds, subsequent invocations will be skipped to get back on schedule.

So if I'm understanding your question correctly, `PeriodicCallback` already does exactly what you want **if your callback is a synchronous function**!

If your callback isn't synchronous, then you will need to use locks to check yourself if something is already running or not. Something like:

```
from tornado import gen, locks

lock = locks.Lock()
running = False
@gen.coroutine
def task():
    global running
    with (yield lock.acquire()):
        if running:
            return
        running = True
    try:
        yield do_something()
    finally:
        with (yield lock.acquire()):
            running = False
```

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback

Comment: But is there a distinction for asyncronous function? In this case how periodicCallback can know if subsequent is finished or not?

Comment: Right, sorry, I missed the asynchronous part of your question. I have amended my answer how I would do it for asynchronous callbacks, but I haven't really tested it, so try it first…

Comment: Ok i'll try it, thanks!. but where can i set the schedule timing? Task() function is started from periodicCallback?

Comment: yes, `task` is just a wrapper around your `do_something` coroutine that you can pass along to `PeriodicCallback` to schedule it

Comment: Ok perfect so it can be:

periodicCallback(task(), 5000) # every 5 seconds
Task() {...} # called from periodic but only if do_something is finished
do_something() {...} # function that do something (maybe longer than 5 seconds...)

Correct? :)

ps: nonlocal is global python statement?

Comment: yes exactly ; nonlocal should actually read `global` here, I'll amend my response